# GOOGLEFINANCE referencing "price", "close", "high", "low"

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change the
`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price")` to
`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,C1)` where C1 contains "price".

Why does that not work?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HnNDwItREk6aN7DpNoTrc6INoVtBXzkpHiJfBb32N-k/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the `"`. That means for C1 type just `price`.